# Action mode submenu and checkableBehavior

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I have a strange issue with submenus and android:checkableBehavior="single". It works fine if the menu is in action bar, but displays check boxes instead of radio buttons if menu is in the action mode. I use AppCompatActivity and create action mode with startActionMode().

menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/priority"
        android:title="@string/priority"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/low_priority"
                    android:title="@string/low_pririty"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/normal_priority"
                    android:title="@string/normal_priority"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/high_priority"
                    android:title="@string/high_priority"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You menu works fine for me using the `startSupportActionMode` method instead of the `startActionMode` method. The `startActionMode` method should not be used when using the support library `AppCompatActivity`.

```
.startSupportActionMode(new android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.test_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Will try it. But why startActionMode shouldn't be used? I didn't see anything about it in the documentation. I developing for API 15+, so I don't use support library's stuff when there is framework's implementation (and it worked fine before I ran into this issue).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also I checked Android source code and found out that startActionMode with AppCompatActivity also uses support library's implementation, wrapping it inside framework's classes. It means that developers intentionally allowed to use startActionMode with AppCompatActivity (otherwise it would return null or raise an exception) and it's a bug.